# IIS hosted .Net 6 Api is returning a response that is not configured anywhere

Tags: rest, .net-core, iis, httpresponse

I am developing a .NET 6 API (which is hosted on IIS 10.0) and I'm encountering an unexpected response that redirects to a different website. Below is my API:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
HttpGet("basic_info/{id}")]
public ActionResult<ResponseWrapper<OrganizationUnitRestResponse>> GetOrganizationUnitResponse(long id)
{
    var unit = _service.OrganizationUnit.GetOrganizationUnit(id) ?? throw new NotFoundException("Organization Unit");

    var res = new ResponseWrapper<OrganizationUnitRestResponse>
    {
        Message = MessageHelper.SuccessfullyGet,
        Success = true,
        Data = _converter.OrganizationUnit.GetOrganizationUnitRestResponse(unit)
    };

    return Ok(res);
}
```

I have also configured a global exception handler as follows:

```
public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
    {
        appError.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (contextFeature != null)
            {
                using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerManager>();

                if (contextFeature.Error is NotFoundException)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                }
                else if (contextFeature.Error is BadRequestException)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                }
                logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {contextFeature.Error}");

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new ResponseWrapper<object>()
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = contextFeature.Error.Message,
                    Data = null
                }));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I have also added exception handler to http request pipeline.

When I execute the API (from Postman) with a valid id I get correct response, but when I request with an Id that does not exist I get following response.

[image]

The status code is incorrect and the response itself, I have not configured in my code.

I have tried running this API on Kestrel (works fine). Same is the case in Development.
The problem maybe related to IIS but I have little experience with IIS.

I'm not sure where it's coming from. Can someone help me identify the source of this response and how to prevent it?

Comment: When a user is redirected to a 404 page for obvious reasons, the page renders an HTTP 200 status code. That route matches the 404 page, which is technically a successful page hit; thus an HTTP 200, but in fact it's still a real 404. 

You can try using FRT to view details about the error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis